Read from txt file and write into map<int, string>
C++
I'm trying to read data from .txt file and store it in a map variable.
But when I try to print map, I get exactly 8 empty line.
I used gpt to create certain part of code (I noted it in comment line)
I have a txt file named "PUBLISHERS.txt":
1  Apress Media
2  John-Wiley
3  McGraw-Hill
4  Microsoft Press
5  Packt Publishing
6  Pearson Education
7  Prentice-Hall

and main.cpp:
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <map>
#include <iomanip>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    // Open Files
    ifstream publishers_file("../Publishers.txt");

    // Error Log if failed
    if (!publishers_file.is_open()) {
        cout << "Error opening input file." << endl;
        return 1;
    }

    // create vector map
    map<int, string> publishers;

    // Read publishers data
    int publisherid;
    string publishername;

    while (publishers_file >> publisherid) {

        getline(publishers_file, publishername);

        //below this line is generated by gpt
        size_t startpos = publishername.find_first_not_of(" \t");
        if (startpos != string::npos) {
            publishername = publishername.substr(startpos);
        } else {
            publishername.clear();
        }

        if (!publishername.empty()) {
            publishers[publisherid] = publishername;
        }
    }

    publishers_file.close();

    // Test
    int i = 0;
    for (const auto& pair : publishers) {
        cout << ++i << ": " << pair.first << " " << pair.second << endl;
    }

    return 0;
}


Cannot reproduce, but also you're doing it the hard way.

Try this?

The I/O manipulator std::ws would be useful to you here, instead of searching for spaces and tabs. It will just eat any whitespace characters in the input. If you have a whole line of input from your file, you can essentially parse the whole thing with: getline(istringstream(line) >> publisherid >> ws, publishername);

@user24714692 I recommend some armour on iss >> publisherid; and getline(iss, publishername); What you have currently suggested would fail with some interesting (very interesting before C++11) results ff the line read was broken.

The strange thing about this question is the claim that the output is exactly 8 empty lines. That's not really possible, given the loop explicitly outputs two integer values and a string literal. Also, the input file apparently contains 7 lines. Perhaps there are unusual characters in the file that are causing the perception of output being empty. A practical approach would be to redirect output to a file, then examine that file in a hex editor. I suspect OP is either not reading the file they think they are, or they are exectuting a different version of their program not shown here.

" //below this line is generated by gpt" - Why on earth would you let a brainless chat bot / language model, that doesn't know the first thing about programming and certainly doesn't have any actual intelligence, write code for you??? That just doesn't make any sense to me.

Side note: you could simplify the code inside the loop by defining publilshername inside the loop. That way it gets created each time through the loop, so you don't have to call clear(). And there's no need for that second if statement. Just if (startpos != std::string::npos) publishers[publisherid] = publishername.substr((startpos);.

And: there's nothing in this code that needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

And: return 1; has no portable meaning. There are three portable return values from main: EXIT_FAILURE, EXIT_SUCCESS, and 0; returning 0 has the same effect as returning EXIT_SUCCESS, but the value of EXIT_SUCCESS does not have to be 0.

@PeteBecker To be specific, on VMS a return value of 1 is considered success and that's what EXIT_SUCCESS is defined as (contrary to most other systems where it's defined as 0). That bit me once and I'll never forget it.
